# Unique value across elements in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

I'm trying to enforce a unique value across an element used in multiple complexType elements.

For example :

```
<xs:element name="lmt">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="lf" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="cdl" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniquePos">
        <xs:selector xpath="./*/pos"/>
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="pos">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{1}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="lf">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="pos"/>
            ... more elements ... 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="cdl">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="pos"/>
            ... more elements ... 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'd like this to fail if I have something like :

```
<lmt>
    <lf>
        <pos>1</pos>
        ... more elements ... 
    </lf>
    <cdl>
        <pos>1</pos>
        ... more elements ... 
    </cdl>
</lmt>
```

but validate

```
<lmt>
    <lf>
        <pos>1</pos>
        ... more elements ... 
    </lf>
    <cdl>
        <pos>2</pos>
        ... more elements ... 
    </cdl>
</lmt>
```

currently both seem to validate.  I've tried both `./*/pos` and `.//pos` for the selector, but either cause the first example to fail validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every B within an element A to have a unique value for C then your uniqueness constraint should be defined on element A, the `selector` expression should select B from A, and the `field` expression should select C from B.

So in your case the constraint should be defined on the container element that you haven't shown us, which has `lf` and `cdl` as its children. The selection should be `.//pos` or perhaps `./*/pos`, and the field should then be `.`

Comment: I've updated the question with an additional level of detail.  Not sure if I've implemented as you've suggested, but using both `.//pos` and `./*/pos` as the selector still allows the case I want to reject to validate.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Figured it out ... needed to use the namespace for the Xpath reference to `pos`.  `<xs:selector xpath="./*/myNameSpace:pos"/>` worked