# Unique attribute value across elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I know how to check for the uniqueness of value of a element when that element exists more than one ([Unique value across elements in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624091/unique-value-across-elements-in-xsd))

However, how can I check the uniqueness of the value of an attribute across elements?   For instance, in the example below I'd like to check to make sure the value of `vinNumber` is always unique.

The example below should fail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="inventory"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:inventory="inventory"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="garage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="inventory:vehicle" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="vehicle">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="inventory:car"/>
                <xs:element ref="inventory:truck"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="car">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="vinNumber" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="truck">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="vinNumber" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<garage xmlns="inventory"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="inventory file:test.xsd">
    <vehicle>
        <car vinNumber="12345">Honda Civic</car>
    </vehicle>

    <vehicle>
        <truck vinNumber="12345">Ford F150</truck>
    </vehicle>

</garage>
```

I've tried the adding `xs:unique` but with no luck.  The example XML still validates even though the `vinNumber` for both `car` and `truck` match

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="inventory"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:inventory="inventory"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="garage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="inventory:vehicle" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="vehicle">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="inventory:car"/>
                <xs:element ref="inventory:truck"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueVin">
            <xs:selector xpath="car | truck"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@vinNumber"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="car">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="vinNumber" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="truck">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="vinNumber" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML schema still allowing duplicate id's with unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893435/xml-schema-still-allowing-duplicate-ids-with-unique)

Comment: I'm not sure this answer addresses the question.  The answer appears to address uniqueness of the attribute in the same element when the parent differs.  I'm looking to enforce uniqueness of a common attribute in different elements.  Let me know if I'm misinterpreting the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Show us a valid XML and a valid XSD. It's too much effort constructing a [mcve] myself.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Added example